# logback printing double quotes with escape sequence

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I am using following code to print logs that should include double quote in output.
Used escape sequence to print double quote but logback prints escape sequence along with double quote

**Code:**

```
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(S3FileWriter.class.getName());
  logger.error("\"hello\"")
```

**output**

```
\"hello\"
```

**desired output**

```
"hello"
```

**Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <property name="component" value="${COMPONENT}"/>
    <property name="componentVersion" value="${COMPONENT_VERSION}"/>
    <property name="logLevel" value="${LOG_LEVEL}"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                            "timestamp": "%date{\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZ\"}",
                            "message": "%message",
                            "component":"${component}",
                            "component_version":"${componentVersion}",
                            "machine":"${HOSTNAME}",
                            "request_id":
                                {
                                    "trace_id":"%X{X-B3-TraceId}",
                                    "span_id":"%X{X-B3-SpanId}",
                                    "parent_span_id":"%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId}"
                                },
                            "data":
                                {
                                    "package":"%logger", "threadId":"%thread"
                                },
                            "exception":"%exception{short}",
                            "stack":"%exception",
                            "level":"%level"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="${logLevel:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], including the logback configuration.

Comment: @Progman added configuration section

Comment: Looks ok. The class `LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder` is encoding the string correcly as it's in json. You just need to remove the quotes from your `logger.error()`

Answer (score 0):

The "extra" escape sequences are added on purpose automatically to ensure the content to add is valid inside the JSON structure you are generating. You have defined the pattern as

```json
{
    ...
    "message": "%message"
    ...
}
```

So when you have the string content `"hello"` as a seven character long string, including the quotes, they have to be added like this:

```json
{
    ...
    "message": "\"hello\""
    ...
}
```

The field `message` will have the (seven charater long string) value `"hello"`. If it would add the content without the quotes it will break the whole JSON structure:

```json
{
    ...
    "message": ""hello""
    ...         ^--- string end
                   ^--- some invalid JSON token
                      ^--- string start
                       ^--- string end
}
```